# How to add bubble sort to my boxes in the code?

Tags: python, sorting, bubble-sort

So first here is my code:

```
import pygame, sys, random
from pygame.locals import *

# Create the constants (go ahead and experiment with different values)
BOARDWIDTH = 4  # number of columns in the board
BOARDHEIGHT = 4 # number of rows in the board
TILESIZE = 80
WINDOWWIDTH = 640
WINDOWHEIGHT = 480
FPS = 30
BLANK = None

#                 R    G    B
BLACK =         (  0,   0,   0)
WHITE =         (255, 255, 255)
BRIGHTBLUE =    (  0,  50, 255)
DARKTURQUOISE = (  3,  54,  73)
GREEN =         (  0, 204,   0)

BGCOLOR = DARKTURQUOISE
TILECOLOR = GREEN
TEXTCOLOR = WHITE
BORDERCOLOR = BRIGHTBLUE
BASICFONTSIZE = 20

BUTTONCOLOR = WHITE
BUTTONTEXTCOLOR = BLACK
MESSAGECOLOR = WHITE

XMARGIN = int((WINDOWWIDTH - (TILESIZE * BOARDWIDTH + (BOARDWIDTH - 1))) / 2)
YMARGIN = int((WINDOWHEIGHT - (TILESIZE * BOARDHEIGHT + (BOARDHEIGHT - 1))) / 2)

UP = 'up'
DOWN = 'down'
LEFT = 'left'
RIGHT = 'right'

def main():
    global FPSCLOCK, DISPLAYSURF, BASICFONT, RESET_SURF, RESET_RECT, NEW_SURF, NEW_RECT, SOLVE_SURF, SOLVE_RECT

    pygame.init()
    FPSCLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()
    DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT))
    pygame.display.set_caption('Slide Puzzle')
    BASICFONT = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', BASICFONTSIZE)

    # Store the option buttons and their rectangles in OPTIONS.
    RESET_SURF, RESET_RECT = makeText('Reset',    TEXTCOLOR, TILECOLOR, WINDOWWIDTH - 120, WINDOWHEIGHT - 90)
    NEW_SURF,   NEW_RECT   = makeText('New Game', TEXTCOLOR, TILECOLOR, WINDOWWIDTH - 120, WINDOWHEIGHT - 60)
    SOLVE_SURF, SOLVE_RECT = makeText('Solve',    TEXTCOLOR, TILECOLOR, WINDOWWIDTH - 120, WINDOWHEIGHT - 30)

    mainBoard, solutionSeq = generateNewPuzzle(80)
    SOLVEDBOARD = getStartingBoard() # a solved board is the same as the board in a start state.
    allMoves = [] # list of moves made from the solved configuration

    while True: # main game loop
        slideTo = None # the direction, if any, a tile should slide
        msg = 'Click tile or press arrow keys to slide.' # contains the message to show in the upper left corner.
        if mainBoard == SOLVEDBOARD:
            msg = 'Solved!'

        drawBoard(mainBoard, msg)

        checkForQuit()
        for event in pygame.event.get(): # event handling loop
            if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                spotx, spoty = getSpotClicked(mainBoard, event.pos[0], event.pos[1])

                if (spotx, spoty) == (None, None):
                    # check if the user clicked on an option button
                    if RESET_RECT.collidepoint(event.pos):
                        resetAnimation(mainBoard, allMoves) # clicked on Reset button
                        allMoves = []
                    elif NEW_RECT.collidepoint(event.pos):
                        mainBoard, solutionSeq = generateNewPuzzle(80) # clicked on New Game button
                        allMoves = []
                    elif SOLVE_RECT.collidepoint(event.pos):
                        resetAnimation(mainBoard, solutionSeq + allMoves) # clicked on Solve button
                        allMoves = []
                else:
                    # check if the clicked tile was next to the blank spot

                    blankx, blanky = getBlankPosition(mainBoard)
                    if spotx == blankx + 1 and spoty == blanky:
                        slideTo = LEFT
                    elif spotx == blankx - 1 and spoty == blanky:
                        slideTo = RIGHT
                    elif spotx == blankx and spoty == blanky + 1:
                        slideTo = UP
                    elif spotx == blankx and spoty == blanky - 1:
                        slideTo = DOWN

            elif event.type == KEYUP:
                # check if the user pressed a key to slide a tile
                if event.key in (K_LEFT, K_a) and isValidMove(mainBoard, LEFT):
                    slideTo = LEFT
                elif event.key in (K_RIGHT, K_d) and isValidMove(mainBoard, RIGHT):
                    slideTo = RIGHT
                elif event.key in (K_UP, K_w) and isValidMove(mainBoard, UP):
                    slideTo = UP
                elif event.key in (K_DOWN, K_s) and isValidMove(mainBoard, DOWN):
                    slideTo = DOWN

        if slideTo:
            slideAnimation(mainBoard, slideTo, 'Click tile or press arrow keys to slide.', 8) # show slide on screen
            makeMove(mainBoard, slideTo)
            allMoves.append(slideTo) # record the slide
        pygame.display.update()
        FPSCLOCK.tick(FPS)


def terminate():
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()


def checkForQuit():
    for event in pygame.event.get(QUIT): # get all the QUIT events
        terminate() # terminate if any QUIT events are present
    for event in pygame.event.get(KEYUP): # get all the KEYUP events
        if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
            terminate() # terminate if the KEYUP event was for the Esc key
        pygame.event.post(event) # put the other KEYUP event objects back


def getStartingBoard():
    # Return a board data structure with tiles in the solved state.
    # For example, if BOARDWIDTH and BOARDHEIGHT are both 3, this function
    # returns [[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, BLANK]]
    counter = 1
    board = []
    for x in range(BOARDWIDTH):
        column = []
        for y in range(BOARDHEIGHT):
            column.append(counter)
            counter += BOARDWIDTH
        board.append(column)
        counter -= BOARDWIDTH * (BOARDHEIGHT - 1) + BOARDWIDTH - 1

    board[BOARDWIDTH-1][BOARDHEIGHT-1] = BLANK
    return board


def getBlankPosition(board):
    # Return the x and y of board coordinates of the blank space.
    for x in range(BOARDWIDTH):
        for y in range(BOARDHEIGHT):
            if board[x][y] == BLANK:
                return (x, y)


def makeMove(board, move):
    # This function does not check if the move is valid.
    blankx, blanky = getBlankPosition(board)

    if move == UP:
        board[blankx][blanky], board[blankx][blanky + 1] = board[blankx][blanky + 1], board[blankx][blanky]
    elif move == DOWN:
        board[blankx][blanky], board[blankx][blanky - 1] = board[blankx][blanky - 1], board[blankx][blanky]
    elif move == LEFT:
        board[blankx][blanky], board[blankx + 1][blanky] = board[blankx + 1][blanky], board[blankx][blanky]
    elif move == RIGHT:
        board[blankx][blanky], board[blankx - 1][blanky] = board[blankx - 1][blanky], board[blankx][blanky]


def isValidMove(board, move):
    blankx, blanky = getBlankPosition(board)
    return (move == UP and blanky != len(board[0]) - 1) or \
           (move == DOWN and blanky != 0) or \
           (move == LEFT and blankx != len(board) - 1) or \
           (move == RIGHT and blankx != 0)


def getRandomMove(board, lastMove=None):
    # start with a full list of all four moves
    validMoves = [UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT]

    # remove moves from the list as they are disqualified
    if lastMove == UP or not isValidMove(board, DOWN):
        validMoves.remove(DOWN)
    if lastMove == DOWN or not isValidMove(board, UP):
        validMoves.remove(UP)
    if lastMove == LEFT or not isValidMove(board, RIGHT):
        validMoves.remove(RIGHT)
    if lastMove == RIGHT or not isValidMove(board, LEFT):
        validMoves.remove(LEFT)

    # return a random move from the list of remaining moves
    return random.choice(validMoves)


def getLeftTopOfTile(tileX, tileY):
    left = XMARGIN + (tileX * TILESIZE) + (tileX - 1)
    top = YMARGIN + (tileY * TILESIZE) + (tileY - 1)
    return (left, top)


def getSpotClicked(board, x, y):
    # from the x & y pixel coordinates, get the x & y board coordinates
    for tileX in range(len(board)):
        for tileY in range(len(board[0])):
            left, top = getLeftTopOfTile(tileX, tileY)
            tileRect = pygame.Rect(left, top, TILESIZE, TILESIZE)
            if tileRect.collidepoint(x, y):
                return (tileX, tileY)
    return (None, None)


def drawTile(tilex, tiley, number, adjx=0, adjy=0):
    # draw a tile at board coordinates tilex and tiley, optionally a few
    # pixels over (determined by adjx and adjy)
    left, top = getLeftTopOfTile(tilex, tiley)
    pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, TILECOLOR, (left + adjx, top + adjy, TILESIZE, TILESIZE))
    textSurf = BASICFONT.render(str(number), True, TEXTCOLOR)
    textRect = textSurf.get_rect()
    textRect.center = left + int(TILESIZE / 2) + adjx, top + int(TILESIZE / 2) + adjy
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(textSurf, textRect)


def makeText(text, color, bgcolor, top, left):
    # create the Surface and Rect objects for some text.
    textSurf = BASICFONT.render(text, True, color, bgcolor)
    textRect = textSurf.get_rect()
    textRect.topleft = (top, left)
    return (textSurf, textRect)


def drawBoard(board, message):
    DISPLAYSURF.fill(BGCOLOR)
    if message:
        textSurf, textRect = makeText(message, MESSAGECOLOR, BGCOLOR, 5, 5)
        DISPLAYSURF.blit(textSurf, textRect)

    for tilex in range(len(board)):
        for tiley in range(len(board[0])):
            if board[tilex][tiley]:
                drawTile(tilex, tiley, board[tilex][tiley])

    left, top = getLeftTopOfTile(0, 0)
    width = BOARDWIDTH * TILESIZE
    height = BOARDHEIGHT * TILESIZE
    pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, BORDERCOLOR, (left - 5, top - 5, width + 11, height + 11), 4)

    DISPLAYSURF.blit(RESET_SURF, RESET_RECT)
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(NEW_SURF, NEW_RECT)
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(SOLVE_SURF, SOLVE_RECT)


def slideAnimation(board, direction, message, animationSpeed):
    #This function does not check if the move is valid.

    blankx, blanky = getBlankPosition(board)
    if direction == UP:
        movex = blankx
        movey = blanky + 1
    elif direction == DOWN:
        movex = blankx
        movey = blanky - 1
    elif direction == LEFT:
        movex = blankx + 1
        movey = blanky
    elif direction == RIGHT:
        movex = blankx - 1
        movey = blanky

    # prepare the base surface
    drawBoard(board, message)
    baseSurf = DISPLAYSURF.copy()
    # draw a blank space over the moving tile on the baseSurf Surface.
    moveLeft, moveTop = getLeftTopOfTile(movex, movey)
    pygame.draw.rect(baseSurf, BGCOLOR, (moveLeft, moveTop, TILESIZE, TILESIZE))

    for i in range(0, TILESIZE, animationSpeed):
        # animate the tile sliding over
        checkForQuit()
        DISPLAYSURF.blit(baseSurf, (0, 0))
        if direction == UP:
            drawTile(movex, movey, board[movex][movey], 0, -i)
        if direction == DOWN:
            drawTile(movex, movey, board[movex][movey], 0, i)
        if direction == LEFT:
            drawTile(movex, movey, board[movex][movey], -i, 0)
        if direction == RIGHT:
            drawTile(movex, movey, board[movex][movey], i, 0)

        pygame.display.update()
        FPSCLOCK.tick(FPS)


def generateNewPuzzle(numSlides):
    # From a starting configuration, make numSlides number of moves (and
    # animate these moves).
    sequence = []
    board = getStartingBoard()
    drawBoard(board, '')
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.time.wait(500) # pause 500 milliseconds for effect
    lastMove = None
    for i in range(numSlides):
        move = getRandomMove(board, lastMove)
        slideAnimation(board, move, 'Generating new puzzle...', animationSpeed=int(TILESIZE / 3))
        makeMove(board, move)
        sequence.append(move)
        lastMove = move
    return (board, sequence)


def resetAnimation(board, allMoves):
    # make all of the moves in allMoves in reverse.
    revAllMoves = allMoves[:] # gets a copy of the list
    revAllMoves.reverse()

    for move in revAllMoves:
        if move == UP:
            oppositeMove = DOWN
        elif move == DOWN:
            oppositeMove = UP
        elif move == RIGHT:
            oppositeMove = LEFT
        elif move == LEFT:
            oppositeMove = RIGHT
        slideAnimation(board, oppositeMove, '', animationSpeed=int(TILESIZE / 2))
        makeMove(board, oppositeMove)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here is the bubble sort code:

```
def shortBubbleSort(alist):
    exchanges = True
    passnum = len(alist)-1
    while passnum > 0 and exchanges:
       exchanges = False
       for i in range(passnum):
           if alist[i]>alist[i+1]:
               exchanges = True
               temp = alist[i]
               alist[i] = alist[i+1]
               alist[i+1] = temp
       passnum = passnum-1

alist=[20,30,40,90,50,60,70,80,100,110]
shortBubbleSort(alist)
print(alist)
```

I am not sure how to select the numbers I have and arrange them using bubble sort method.

Comment: Your indentation is off to start.

Comment: I know I just had to edit the indentation here

Comment: I'm confused about your question.  The method shows that you pass in a list.  If you have a list in your code you simply pass that and bubble sort will handle the rest.

Comment: Michael Platt, [link](http://prntscr.com/hdr75v) I got these boxes i gotta sort

Comment: Can you post the relevant code here?  Posting links to your code isn't something that is standard to So.

Comment: What is the role of `passnum` in your code?

Comment: @james it helps with some efficiency stuff

Comment: @MichaelPlatt done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh - I found your code very complex for python and bubble-sort.

Here is the my view:

```
def bubbleSort(alist):
    for passnum in range(len(alist)-1, 0, -1):
        for i in range(passnum):
            if alist[i] > alist[i+1]:
              alist[i] , alist[i+1] = alist[i+1] , alist[i]

alist = [54,26,93,17,77,31,44,55,20]
bubbleSort(alist)
print(alist)
```

You do not need any flags or temp variables - this is the python, the language of magic! :) :) :) abracadabra!!!

Comment: Ok but how do i integrate it with my code so the boxes will get sorted according to the bubble sort

Comment: The boxes I have.. run the game, and u will see

Comment: Okay. I hope you understand that I can not run your code? :)
This is the only part of source code - and I do not have modules that you are using.

For example you are importing constants and declare them as global
BUT we have no these constants in your code. :)

I am talking about your import: from pygame.locals import *

Comment: Here are the boxes (http://prntscr.com/hdrq4o) so the goal of the game is to order the boxes from 1 to 15.. u can also use the solve button, but id like to add more algorithms

Comment: You board is initially sorted. So do not need to sort it.

Just look into your code:

Function - generateNewPuzzle(numSlides)
...
board = getStartingBoard()
...

At this moment your board is sorted.
Than it makes random moves to makes board mixed here:

for i in range(numSlides):
....

You may just comment that loop and you will get initially sorted board.

Or you want to write algorithm to solve puzzle?
This will be not easy. Are you familiar with graphs theory?

Comment: want to write algorithm to solve puzzle, and i am not familiar with it.. im just an 8th grader

Comment: i want to use the bubble algorithm

Comment: Yes - you may use any sorting algorithm - but this will not be the solution. :)
Because, you can not swap cards by rules.
In your game - solve button - just play all moves in opposite direction - this is not a solution algorithm.
To implement real solution algorithm need to use complex mathematical methods, and be familiar with math subjects as graphs theory, sets theory, etc. I think you will be able to do that in University - in case you will choose the path of math sciences.